# Вопрос по .htaccess как записать то что после доменного имени в переменную q

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Как сделать так что бы он записывал в переменную q все что после доменного имени, например:

Перешел человек по ссылке site.ru/users, он записал в q и дальше по этому q мы выводим то что нужно пользователю.

Основной код:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect()
header('Content-type: json/application');

$type = $_GET['q'];

if($type === 'posts'){
    $posts = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM default_db.posts');

    $postsList = [];

    while ($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts)){
        $postsList[] = $post;
    }

    echo json_encode($postsList);
}
```

Код .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?=$1 [L,QSA]
```

После выполнения кода скачивается какой то файл, а если использовать site.ru/users то выводит это: [image: 1]

Comment: content-type измените на `application/json` и не будет скачиваться какой-то файл, а выдаваться json ваш